# Chained if/else statements in the IO Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm wondering if there is an idiomatic way to write control code similar to chained if/else statements in an imperative language in the IO Monad.

So in a language like Python, I would typically right something like this:

```py
if οs.path.isdir(fname):
    # do whatever
elif os.path.isfile(fname):
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```

The best I could come up in Haskell is the following:

```
isf <- doesFileExist path
isd <- if isf then return False else doesDirectoryExist path
case (isf, isd) of
    (True,  _)      -> return ...
    (_,     True)   -> return ...
    _               -> return ...
```

Which is not as good, and I am wondering if there is a better way to write this sort of thing.

Also, to validate my understanding: the `if isf` part in `isd <- ...` is required in the case of the IO Monad, if you don't  want to always do both operations. My guess would be that in other Monads (lazy Monads?), this would not be needed because `isd` would be evaluated lazily.

**Edit**

Based on the first comments, I ended up with the following:

```
firstMatchM :: (Monad m) => a -> [(a -> m Bool, b)] -> b -> m b
firstMatchM arg [] def   = return def
firstMatchM arg ((check,x):xs) def = do
    t <- check arg
    if t then return x else firstMatchM arg xs def

doFirstM :: (Monad m) => a -> [(a -> m Bool, a -> m b)] -> (a -> m b) -> m b
doFirstM arg acts def = do
    fm <- firstMatchM arg acts def
    fm arg

handlePath2 path = doFirstM path
   [( \p -> doesFileExist p,
         \p ->  return "file"
   ),(\p -> doesDirectoryExist p,
         \p -> return "dir"
   )] $ \p -> return "Error"
```

Which is similar to @chi's second suggestion, bit I prefer `ifM`, because it's closer to the imperative version.

Comment: but even in python you should refactor those ;)

Comment: OK, I'll bite, How? :)

Comment: Well, you could do something like build a list of actions and use stuff like `foldM` or `forM` etc. to obtain the result you want. This would generalize to any number of `elif`s although it would be cumbersome for only 3 cases. The same would be true in python: `for test, action in tests_and_actions: if test(input): action(input)`.

Comment: @ynimous for example into 3 functions/actions each `guard`ing ;) then you could just sequence them ;) (of course `when` will also do)

Comment: You can make the `ifM` version [slightly nicer](http://ideone.com/tBj6M3).

Comment: @user3237465 That link no longer works. If you remember what it contained, could you please post it here as an answer?

Comment: @Chris Martin, `ideone` was down, but it works now. It's nothing interesting, just an infixl alias for `ifM`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we don't want to involve monad transformers, a basic option is rolling our own monadic `if`:

```
ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
ifM act t e = do
  b <- act
  if b then t else e
```

Then the code structure is similar to the one in imperative languages:

```
test :: IO String
test = ifM anAction (do
          putStrLn "branch a"
          return "a")
       $ ifM otherAction (do
          putStrLn "branch b"
          return "b")
       $ return "none"
```

where `anAction, otherAction :: IO Bool`.

Alternatively, use something like

```
ifChain :: [(IO Bool, IO a)] -> IO a -> IO a
ifChain [] e = e
ifChain ((g, a) : acts) e = do
   b <- g
   if b then a else ifChain acts e
```

Comment: I like the `ifM` better, I think. How would you do it with monadic transformers?

Comment: @ynimous I tried monad transformers (`MaybeT`), but I didn't like the result: too many `lift`s and boilerplate code. Maybe someone else can post some code which is actually readable.